# I am trying to write a SQL subquery in linq

Tags: linq, lambda

I am trying to write a subquery in linq here is my SQL script

```
Select id, name from employee where id in (select dictinct id in salaryEmp)
```

I have tried several combination but not getting the desired output. I will appreciate any help in this regards

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
db.employee
 .Where(x => salaryEmp.Select(x => x.id).Distinct().Contains(x.id))
 .Select(x => new { x.id, x.name });
```

Or better you can do:

```
var idList = salaryEmp.Select(x => x.id).Distinct().ToList();

var result = db.employee
.Where(x => idList.Contains(x.id))
.Select(x => new { x.id, x.name });
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how your context looks like, but it will be something like that:

```
from e in ctx.employee
where
    (from s in ctx.salaryEmp
     select s.Id).Distinct().Contains(e.id)
select new { e.Id, e.Name }
```

or with sub query as method-based query:

```
from e in ctx.employee
where ctx.salaryEmp.Select(s => s.Id).Distinct().Contains(e.id)
select new { e.Id, e.Name }
```